# ItemAdding getting the file name of a document

Tags: 2010, development, event-handlers, document, item

I have a document library. I want to add an `itemadding` event recieiever to do some validation on the file name of the document. How can I get the file name from the `SPItemEventProperties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListItem is not available in ItemAdding.  This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Properties.AfterUrl
```

and then split it by "/" and get the second part of string to get document Name, it does work for item adding or item updating.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `SP.ListItem.get_file();`

[SP.ListItem.file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553806.aspx)  A sample code is mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/10/02/programmatically-rename-a-file-inside-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx)

Comment: I thought ListItem was null on the ItemAdding Event?